# Is there some Java equivalent of javaScripts **new Function([arg1[, arg2[, ...argN]],] functionBody)**

Tags: java, reflection

I want to create a function at run time in JAVA.
I want some thing like java Scripts equivalent of:

```
new Function([arg1[, arg2[, ...argN]],] functionBody)
```

So the user can specify function as a string, and thereafter can invoke it using the required parameters.

Comment: the "user" of an application or the "user" / programmer using a library?

Comment: sorry, but could not get your question, could you please elaborate.  
Actually user will give function body as first input and then will give the parameter, the result of the executed function will be returned.

Comment: *I want to create a function at run time in JAVA* Java is a type-safe and **compiled** language.

Comment: Java 9 comes with JShell, also embeddable.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few things in that direction in Java, but the closest would probably be the [Java Scripting API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/prog_guide/api.html) which "is used to embed scripts in your Java applications".

NB if the code you want to execute is provided by the user, make sure you execute it in a sandboxed environment, otherwise you'll be hurt.